# Unable to deserialize JSON response into Java Objects

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

I know there are lots of queries on this topic but nothing has been helpful for me to resolve below issue

```
    {
  "_embedded": {
    "customers": [
      {
        "id": 101,
        "name": "John",
        "city": "Ohio"
      },
      {
        "id": 102,
        "name": "Tom",
        "city": "London"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

for this I have created below Java objects:

```
@Data
public class Wrapper {
    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    private Customers customer;
  }

@Data
public class Customers {
@JsonProperty("customer")
private List<Foo> obj;
}

@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Foo{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first of all in JSON you have `"customers"` but in class `@JsonProperty("customer")`

Comment: Pls give informative amount of logs of exception. Also, your naming is incorrect - `_embedded` and `customers` is really not informative of the object(nothing to do with exception but for our understanding). As @Maciej pointed out watch out for the property name.

Comment: Also you annotaded the yuestion with jackson but seem to use Gson...

Comment: @Maciej Its typo here but in my actual program I have used object names as in the JSON file

Comment: @KarthikR : Here its typo but I have named object names as per Json Objects and the stack of errors I have added in description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some naming issues in your original question, but disregarding that, you could structure your classes according to the JSON to make it easier for both yourself and `Gson`.

Something like this would work:

```
public class JsonWrapper {
    public Embedded _embedded;
}


public class Embedded {
    public Customers customers;
}


public class Customers extends ArrayList<Foo>{ }


public class Foo{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String city;
}


String json = "{\"_embedded\":{\"customers\":[{\"id\":101,\"name\":\"John\",\"city\":\"Ohio\"},{\"id\":102,\"name\":\"Tom\",\"city\":\"London\"}]}}";
JsonWrapper wrapper = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonWrapper.class);
```

Comment: How about 
```List<Foo> customers;```
instead of
```Customers customers;```

Comment: @HK0909 Great! Don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: @MagnusW I have already implemented this code in my script and its working now.Thanks a lot you resolved issue for which I was struggling for days. Whats the way to accept answer..? May be I am aware of that.

Comment: @HK0909 You're welcome! You can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark sign at the top left of the answer.